# Schedule R Script Every 15 min (cronR)

Tags: r, cron

I need to schedule/run an R script every 15 min.  Running on an AWS RStudio instance.

I have played a bit with 'cronR', including loading the add-in.  I can figure out how to get it to run "minutely", "hourly", etc...but not every 15-min.

What's the best way to get this done...either in RStudio via cronR or alternative, or via some other method?

Comment: Good question ... the docs clearly say *"or any complex schedule"*, yet the code clearly [does not provide "override" capability](https://github.com/bnosac/cronR/blob/master/R/cron_add.R#L111-L149).

Comment: Why are you trying to do it from inside R? Why not run a cron job?

Comment: @RonakShah - Open to any alternatives to accomplish the goal.  I am new to the cron space.  Can you give me some guidance on how to accomplish what I need outside of R?

Comment: @r2evans - Totally.  Went through every doc/thread I could find...nothing on the more "complex" timings,

Comment: Using Cron directly might be the easiest approach. And it doesn't seem the code does allow the complex scheduling it claims. One could have the script run every minute though but modify the script to check the current time and only run the actual code if the time and in 0, 15, 30, or 45.

Comment: The right approach might to request this capability (via an [issue on github](https://github.com/bnosac/cronR/issues)). The simplest and most immediate fix is likely to edit the resulting file yourself: set the job to be "minutely", and then change the first asterisk to be `*/15` for every 15 minutes. (But that assumes you have shell access on the server, or you can use `system('crontab -l')`, save to a tempfile, then `system('crontab tempfile')`.)

Answer (score 3):

So I followed @r2evans advice and opened an issue on git.  It was addressed almost immediately with a fix to the code and an update to the readme.  Figured I would answer this for completeness in case someone else ever finds their way here...

You can now schedule a job every 15 min with 'cronR' either in the RStudio add-in, or with the following code:

```
cron_add(script, frequency = '*/15 * * * *', id = 'Job ID', description = 'Every 15 min')
```

One note is that you might need to reinstall the package using devtools to push through the most recent changes:

```
devtools::install_github("bnosac/cronR")
```